# Why does git bisect not decrease the number of revisions left to test after this?

Tags: git

I understand that maybe it's a bad question without showing my real git log, but maybe the question still can be answered in general so to speak, so I will try.

I was doing git bisect to find a "bad" commit. And at some point I started to get

```
Bisecting: 40 revisions left to test after this (roughly 5 steps)
```

where 40 then after a couple of `git bisect good`, `git bisect bad` commands, made by me, only switched to 39, and then again after a couple of `git bisect good`, `git bisect bad` commands switched to 38. And I always get these `roughly 5 steps`. So I understand that, as building the revision costs around 25 minutes to me, there is really no sense for me to continue.

What can be wrong? The only point I can think about is the fact that I do quite many `git bisect skip` commands, as some revisions alas cannot be built. But I am not sure if it should spoil the whole git bisect procedure completely.

Comment: How does your history look? How many branches do you have in parallel and how many merge requests?

Answer (score 2):

This truly depends on your specific history, so we would need to check your repository to make our minds here, but the first thing one have to keep in mind here is that `good` is forcibly *upstream* with respect to `bad`.

That's why synonyms `old` and `new` have been introduced later, then `--term-old` and `--term-new`.

It also depends on how many branches and merge points lies between the first `good` point and last `bad` one. As long as there's only a single branch, bisecting is easily done. Otherwise, Git needs to check them out individually.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. The docs says: "You use it by first telling it a "bad" commit that is known to contain the bug, and a "good" commit that is known to be before the bug was introduced." So git bisect expects it to be: [past, good] ---> [now, bad], is not it?

Comment: Right. That's why I always use `old` and `new` instead.